# IN CNN not able to Train all my sample images

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

the program terminates after training 250 samples but i have 8000 samples

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 8000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/10
 250/8000 [..............................] - ETA: 22:48 - loss: 0.6887 - accuracy: 0.5336
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 80000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
 250/8000 [..............................] - 52s 209ms/step - loss: 0.6887 - accuracy: 0.5336 - val_loss: 0.6726 - val_accuracy: 0.6005
```

---Code ----

```
model.fit(training_set,steps_per_epoch = 8000,epochs=10, validation_data=test_set)
```

Comment: Did you use Keras image data generator.flow fromdirectory? IF so what was the batch size?

Comment: I think he used tf.Data.dataset. During data creation make sure to use ```dataset.repeat()``` for training data after train/valid split. I also recommend batching in groups of 32 and setting steps_per_epoch=train_images/batches to make sure entire training set is included